# Printing values from multiple arrays to the console in watir

Tags: ruby, arrays, watir

I have a ruby array code which does the below

```
array = a.split("\n")                 
array.size.times do |i|   
p array[i]
```

This gives me the below result:

```
First Name, Last Name, Emp ID, Emp Sal.
```

Now I have another array which does:

```
b.tds.each do |r| p r.text end
```

This gives me:

```
Reed, Taylor, 1000, $70000.
```

I am trying to combine both these arrays and trying to get a result like

```
First Name   Reed, Last Name Taylor, EmpID 1000, Emp Sal 70000.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Array#transpose`:

```
Hash[[array, b.tds.map(&:text)].transpose].each do |key, value|
  puts "#{key}: #{value}"      
end
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg! Tried the same and I am getting the below error "TypeError: no implicit conversion of Watir::TableDataCellCollection into Array
from (pry):5:in `transpose'"

Comment: @TGR, try `b.tds.to_a`. Updated the code. Let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: Looks like I am only getting the key value. This is how the result is looking now.  {"    First Name"=>
#<Watir::TableDataCell:0x2ba7a88e located=false selector={:element=>(webdriver element)}>,
Last Name"=>
#<Watir::TableDataCell:0x..fceb08bc6 located=false selector={:element=>(webdriver element)}>,
Business Role Name"=>

Comment: @TGR please try again with `b.tds.map(&:text)`